# Windows phone 7: button click, background and text-color, why?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, button

i have my button:

completely trasparent, text in white.
But when i click it, the background goes white and the text black, and it seems to move up :-|
i want only execute the action, i don't want those strange effects. any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's the default behaviour of Button control,
if you want to avoid it you have some options:

1. Use another control like textBlock and use OnMouseLeftButtonDown/Up
2. Customize the template of your button: See the link bellow, this is default style of a button, you can copy/paste the Template part and modify it as you want. (You need to play with different visual states)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278069(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: i've used the textBlock, and it's ok! but when i click, it seems to move up, what the hell?

Comment: what do you mean it "moves up"?

Comment: i mean that, when i click it, it seems to move up by itself... literally "moves up" :-(

Comment: That's strange, I have used this  tricks lots if times. I can help you more if I see your code

Comment: <TextBlock Height="163" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="24,207,0,0" Name="buttonsend" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" FontSize="32" Text="" MouseLeftButtonUp="button_send" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment" />

Comment: How do you see it when it doesn't have text?! Does your event handler change anything in UI?

Comment: i put the text via c# because i grab it online, or write it via .text= if offline